# Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS missing packages libilbc3 libplacebo264 libvapoursynth-script0

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Trying to update the server and keep running into this error in the past month, waited a bit in hope that the packages become available but had no luck.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libavcodec59 : Depends: libilbc3 (>= 3.0.4) but it is not installable libavfilter8 : Depends: libplacebo264 (>= 5.264.1) but it is not installable libavformat59 : Depends: libvapoursynth-script0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

My attempts to install the missing packages by apt-get install ends up to errors like below

E: Package 'libplacebo264' has no installation candidate

Any hints on how to find these packages, and fix the issue in another way, are very much appreciated. libilbc3 is available for Debian as it seems but I could not find it for Ubuntu.

Comment: Were you trying to install a package (not shown in the question) that itself was not available in Ubuntu 18.04 during the past month?

Comment: Likewise, libilbc3 might be available *for* Debian, but not *from* Debian. https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian . Anyway, here's a rope: https://www.deb-multimedia.org/ (don't attempt any dist/full upgrade before you remove all such packages, it will likely fail)

Comment: No, I was just doing the routine OS upgrades when ran into this issue. The only change I made that I can recall, I removed the deprecated PHP module from PHP 8.1 and installing one of two packages for FCGI which went smoothly. Other than those, can not recall any more changes. Thanks for the help.